# How to deduct a number from a column in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of `9` columns and I want to delete a specific number from all numbers in column `6` but I don't want to ruin the structure of data frame. I want to deduct `383` from the column `6`. How to do it?

```
my.data.frame11<-read.table("dir1/Water_Level/V3015010.txt",skip=4,header=T,sep=";")
head(my.data.frame11)

  X920 X1 V3015010 X19691027 X10.37 X480.000 X9 X2  X
1  920  1 V3015010  19691027  16:06      490  9  2 NA
2  920  1 V3015010  19691101  00:50      490  9  2 NA
3  920  1 V3015010  19691103  08:09      480  9  2 NA
4  920  1 V3015010  19691103  10:59      480  9  2 NA
5  920  1 V3015010  19691105  12:18      480  9  2 NA
6  920  1 V3015010  19691105  13:37      490  9  2 NA
```

If I use the following code

```
my.data.frame11[, 6] <- my.data.frame11[, 6] - 383
```

I got error:

> Error in my.data.frame11[, 6] : incorrect number of dimensions

After I changed the header into `false` by the following command:

```
my.data.frame11[, 6] <- my.data.frame11[, 6] - 383
```

gave me the desired results.
Thank you all for the help and having patience with me.

Comment: In column 6, there is no 383 in the example showed.  what is your expected output?  Do you want to change those 383 to NA?

Comment: I want to deduct from column 6 (480, 490, etc the following number 383) and than save it.

Comment: Your title says `delete` now it is `deduct`.  What exactly do you want?

Comment: Sorry for the usage of wrong words. I want to deduct the 383 from a specific column.

Comment: Please show your expected output and also an example that have 383

Comment: 1  920  1 V3015010  19691027  16:06      107  9  2 NA
2  920  1 V3015010  19691101  00:50      107 9  2 NA
3  920  1 V3015010  19691103  08:09       97  9  2 NA
4  920  1 V3015010  19691103  10:59       97  9  2 NA
5  920  1 V3015010  19691105  12:18       97  9  2 NA
6  920  1 V3015010  19691105  13:37     107  9  2 NA

Comment: Please update it in your post.  Can you read it from the comments?

Comment: Do you mean subtract 383 from every element of the column? That would be `df1[, 6] <- df1[, 6] - 383`. It's best to post such content in your question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here and I just getting familiar how to do things.

Comment: Yes I want to subtract 383 from every element of the column witch is 65452 characters long.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?  The code you posted looks like it *should* work, so there might be something funny about your data frame.  At the very least, could we see the results of `str(my.dataframe11)`?  (Also, you should probably be using `header=FALSE` when you read the data in ...)

Comment: Thank you all for the help. Ben Bolker thank you for the comment when I changed header to false I got the desiring results. Now I need to save this data to a new usable txt file.